# Read attribute/value pairs from XML file using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, deserialization

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Leads/getRecords">
   <Leads>
      <row no="1">
         <FL val="LEADID">2000000022020</FL>
         <FL val="SMOWNERID">2000000018005</FL>
         <FL val="Lead Owner">John</FL>
         <FL val="Company">Zillium</FL>
         <FL val="First Name">Scott</FL>
         <FL val="Last Name">James</FL>
         <FL val="Designation">null</FL>
         <FL val="Email">null</FL>
         <FL val="Phone">null</FL>
         <FL val="Fax">null</FL>
         <FL val="Mobile">null</FL>
         <FL val="Website">null</FL>
         <FL val="Lead Source">null</FL>
         <FL val="Lead Status">null</FL>
         <FL val="No of Employees">0</FL>
         <FL val="Annual Revenue">0.0</FL>
      </row>
      <row no="2">
         <FL val="LEADID">2000000022020</FL>
         <FL val="SMOWNERID">2000000018005</FL>
         <FL val="Lead Owner">John</FL>
         <FL val="Company">Zillium</FL>
         <FL val="First Name">Scott</FL>
         <FL val="Last Name">James</FL>
         <FL val="Designation">null</FL>
         <FL val="Email">null</FL>
         <FL val="Phone">null</FL>
         <FL val="Fax">null</FL>
         <FL val="Mobile">null</FL>
         <FL val="Website">null</FL>
         <FL val="Lead Source">null</FL>
         <FL val="Lead Status">null</FL>
         <FL val="No of Employees">0</FL>
         <FL val="Annual Revenue">0.0</FL>
      </row>
   </Leads>
</response>
```

I am trying to read the "key/value" pairs in the row element, but I can't seem to get at grasp on how to do it using Linq.

I need to "de-serialize" the data into a simple POCO

```
public class Leads
{
    public long LEADID { get; set; }
    public long SMOWNERID { get; set; }
    public string LeadOwner { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string LeadSource { get; set; }
    public string LeadStatus { get; set; }
    public int NoOfEmployees { get; set; }
    public decimal AnnualRevenue { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is, that all the elements have the same name  so I need to get the attribut value (val) paired with the element value.

So my question is, is there a smart way to do this using Linq.

Otherwise my workaround would be to write an XLS and transform the XML into a more de-serializeable XML format.

Comment: It is doable with linq to xml but the XSLT will be so much nicer and elegant see [Deserialize elements to properties based on attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093422/deserialize-elements-to-properties-based-on-attribute/14094085#14094085).

Comment: @Rafal you're absolutely right, and that is how I would normally do i. but this question was because I would like to know more about Linq ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select each value like

```
let company = (string)r.Elements()
                       .Single(x => (string)x.Attribute("val") == "Company")
```

But I believe that projecting all elements into dictionary will work faster (and is much more readable)

```
var query = 
     xdoc.Descendants("row")
         .Select(r => r.Elements().ToDictionary(f => (string)f.Attribute("val")))
         .Select(d => new Leads {
             LEADID = (long)d["LEADID"],
             SMOWNERID = (long)d["SMOWNERID"],
             Company = (string)d["Company"]
             // etc
         });
```

Also keep in mind you need to use `long` for first two properties (according to values in sample xml).

Comment: So what is returned? a query of what type,
How can I get the data out from the Leads object?

Comment: @Verakso query is a `IEnumerable<Leads>`. Work with leads object as with any other objects in your program. You can convert them to list `var leadsList = query.ToList()` or simply use in foreach loop

Comment: I have chosen this answer, since it was easier to debug, than the other great example. Not only did I learn something about Linq, but I also learned a new thing Lambda expression - sweat.

Comment: I noticed that the example uses explicit cast, e.g. `Company = (string)d["Company"]`but wouldn't it be more propper to write `Company = d["Company"].Value.ToString()`?

Comment: @Verakso explicit cast allows you to convert attribute value to long, int, DateTime, etc. Also inside operator implemented as `Int64.Parse(attribute.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
xdoc.Elements("response").Elements("Leads").Elements("row").Select(l => new Leads() 
{
    LEADID = (long)l.Elements("FL").Where(fl => (string)fl.Attribute("val") == "LEADID").FirstOrDefault(),
    SMOWNERID = (long)l.Elements("FL").Where(fl => (string)fl.Attribute("val") == "SMOWNERID").FirstOrDefault(),
    etc..
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean:
`LEADID = (int)l.Elements("FL").Where((string)l.Attribute("val") == "LEADID").FirstOrDefault(),`
And what can I have missed? I get the error that System.Xml.Linq.XElement does not contain a definition for Where...

Comment: Sorry, i had an error there. I've updated the post, should hopefully work now. Make sure you include a "Using System.Xml.Linq;"

Comment: @Tallek: You still have one typo there: `Elements("Response")` needs to be `Elements("response")`, otherwise you get an empty list.

Comment: Is there a need to do the traversing as done in this example, couldn't is as easily have been done by using `xdoc.Descendants("row").Select(....`

Comment: @Verakso That should work just as well. I just prefer to be a little more specific about what I want. If you know the xml will never change, that is fine, but if for some reason a new element is added that also has 'row' elements under it, you don't want to be suddenly broken.