# How to ready xml response result in c# or linq asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

Below is my response result in xml,

```
<response uri="/recruit/private/xml/Candidates/addRecords">
 <result>
   <message>Record(s) added successfully</message>
     <recorddetail>
       <FL val="Id">316886000014241044</FL>
       <FL val="Created Time">2018-12-14 20:26:50</FL>
       <FL val="Modified Time">2018-12-14 20:26:50</FL>
       <FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[d Pvt Ltd]]></FL>
       <FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[d Pvt Ltd]]></FL>
     </recorddetail>
  </result>
</response>
```

I am using below code to get output

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 string myResponse = "";
 using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new 
 System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
 {
 myResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
 }
 Response.Write(myResponse);

var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(myResponse);xdoc.Elements("response").Elements("result").Elements("message").Elements("recorddetail").Select(l => new Leads()
{
ID = (string)l.Elements("FL").Where(fl => (string)fl.Attribute("val") == "Id").FirstOrDefault(),
});

public class Leads
{

public string ID { get; set; }

}
```

but i am getting output from above code: **ID= _Page**

I want two output like Id value and message value like  below

```
 1)316886000014241044
 2)Record(s) added successfully
```

I have prefer this example

[Read attribute/value pairs from XML file using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937606/read-attribute-value-pairs-from-xml-file-using-linq/14937772#14937772)

if any other approach other than linq also helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get descendants of node `result` and then for `message` you have to read node `message` and select its value and for `id` you have to  read all node with name `FL` matching attribute value for `Id` and select its value like

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myResponse);

var result = doc.Descendants("result");

string message = result.Elements("message").Select(x => (string)x)?.FirstOrDefault();
string id = result.Elements("recorddetail").Elements("FL").Where(x => x.Attribute("val").Value == "Id")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

Console.WriteLine($"id: {id}");
Console.WriteLine($"message: {message}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the code and release the resources.

No need to create an extra `StreamReader`.

All Disposable objects wrap in `using`.

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(responseStream);

    var leads = xdoc.Root
        .Elements("result")
        .Elements("recorddetail")
        .Elements("FL")
        .Where(fl => fl.Attribute("val").Value == "Id")
        .Select(fl => new Leads { ID = fl.Value });
}
```